# Better way of generating an alphanumeric 50 char long GUID

Tags: c#

I am generating 2 GUIDs and taking the first 50 chars from them. What is the better way of doing this -

```
string tr1 = string.Join("", Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n"));
string tr2 = string.Join("", Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n"));

string full = ( tr1 + "@" + tr2).Left(50);
```

Comment: Define "better".

Comment: Why you need to do that, BTW? Why not just use the generated GUID?

Comment: Do you just want 50 random hex characters?  Use RNGCryptoServiceProvider.GetBytes and then convert the resulting bytes into a hex string.  If that's what you want, I'll write it up as an answer.

Comment: Seems odd to need something longer than a normal GUID, those things are almost certainly enough for all purposes.

Comment: The regular GUID created by `Guid.NewGuid` is already a "Globally Unique Identifier". Adding more numbers won't make it that much more "Globally Unique" for any normal use

Comment: What is the idea behind using `string.Join` in this scenario? I mean, it doesn't actually join anything. Does it?

Comment: @Flydog57 GUID => **G**lobally **U**nique **ID**entifier - RNGCryptoServiceProvider has focus on random and not on unique

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Well, it does join the chars from the input and the result is the same as the input. It will only force some useless workload to the cpu :o)

Comment: GUIDs are globally unique because the likelihood of picking two identical 120-something bit numbers is infinitesimal.  The likelihood of picking two identical 200 bit numbers is 2 to the 70-something-th more infinitessimal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't what you asked for, but I think it's what you want:

```
  using System.Security.Cryptography;

  public static string Get50RandomHexNybls()
  {
      var bytes = new byte[25];
      var rand = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
      rand.GetBytes(bytes);
      return BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", string.Empty);
  }
```

The result looks like:

```
B7EB8387438D55CAEC2C9D4EE73E8B99BB146EEDA4F8A9CB48
```

with a different result each time.  If you don't like how I converted the bytes to a hex string, take a look at "[How do you convert a byte array to a hexadecimal string, and vice versa"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa)

Comment: It's a 200 bit cryptographically strong random number.  It's a _**Lot**_ more unique than a Guid.  See: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080627-00/?p=21823

Comment: `GUIDs are globally unique because the likelihood of picking two identical 120-something bit numbers is infinitesimal` No, GUIDs are _not_ "unique" because of that. The same article you just posted tells you why. The implementation of GUIDs focuses on the uniqueness, not the randomness.

Comment: Sorry, bad link.  .NET uses version 4 Guids: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29  They are 122-bit random numbers with a few more bits to establish the algorithm.  A 200-bit random number is 2 to the 78th more random.  They are unique